# Jquery Accordion data from database using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, accordion

How to get the parent and child data from the database and how to make the accordion.I want use the accordion in joomla. Please help me.My table is below

[image]

I want this formate accordion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not joomla but it is possible that the jquery dataTable plugin may work for you as it has  parent / child relationship.

http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

[image]

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Full name:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
        '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
        '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        {
            "class":          'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  } );
 } );
```